# COVID-19: size, real image

Tags: coronavirus, image-processing

I'm an electronics engineer. I was thinking about how to detect the presence of COVID-19:

1. Obtain the sample.
2. Increment image/sample, (I need the real size to determine increment/magnification)
3. Digital image processing — detect presence using artificial intelligence or Recognition.

What is the approximate size of COVID-19? Is there a real image of COVID-19?

Comment: Reading good please, I'm asking for size and images proper of Biology field.

Comment: @tyersome The question asks simply the size of Coronavirus. It does not ask about image recognition.

Comment: SE Biology is concerned with the mechanisms of biological processes. General information about the coronavirus is available from a variety of reputable sources, some of which are listed [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses/4036#4036). As your concern is for detection of the virus you would be well advised to consult such sources for information about how this is currently performed and the problems actually faced. Others have hammers too, and don’t necessary think that everything is a nail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2019-nCoV also has enveloped virions that measure approximately 50–200 nm in diameter
>   with a single positive-sense RNA genome.

- [Epidemiological and clinical characteristics of 99 cases of 2019 novel coronavirus pneumonia in Wuhan, China: a descriptive study](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(20)30211-7/fulltext), The Lancet (2020)